# Get the average of the selected cells line by line in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, average

I have a single file with the multiple columns. I want to select few and get average for selected cell in a line and output the entire average as column.

For example:

```
Month    Low.temp     Max.temp     Pressure      Wind       Rain 
JAN       17             36           120          5          0
FEB       10             34           110          15         3  
MAR       13             30           115          25         5
APR       14             33           105          10         4
.......
```

How to get average temperature (Avg.temp) and Humidity (Hum)as column?

```
Avg.temp = (Low.temp+Max.temp)/2

Hum = Wind * Rain
```

To get the Avg.temp

```
Month    Low.temp     Max.temp     Pressure      Wind       Rain   Avg.temp      Hum
JAN       17             36           120          5          0      26.5          0
FEB       10             34           110          15         3       22          45  
MAR       13             30           115          25         5      21.5        125
APR       14             33           105          10         4      23.5         40
.......
```

I don't want to do it in excel. Is there any simple shell command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0, "Avg.temp", "Hum"; next} {$(NF+1)=($2+$3)/2; $(NF+1)=$5*$6}1' file
```

or:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0, "Avg.temp", "Hum"; next} {print $0, ($2+$3)/2, $5*$6}' file
```

This consists in doing the calculations and appending them to the original values.

Let's see it in action, piping to `column -t` for a nice output:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {print $0, "Avg.temp", "Hum"; next} {$(NF+1)=($2+$3)/2; $(NF+1)=$5*$6}1' file | column -t
Month  Low.temp  Max.temp  Pressure  Wind  Rain  Avg.temp  Hum
JAN    17        36        120       5     0     26.5      0
FEB    10        34        110       15    3     22        45
MAR    13        30        115       25    5     21.5      125
APR    14        33        105       10    4     23.5      40
```

Comment: Thanks for your input ..                                                                          awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1 {print $0, "Avg.temp", "Hum"; next} {print $0, ($2+$3)/2, ($5*$6)*2}' file      ................        worked pretty well

Comment: @fedorqui: `$(NF+1)=($2+$3)/2; $(NF+2)=$5*$6` should be `$(NF+1)=($2+$3)/2; $(NF+1)=$5*$6`. The first assignment increases `NF`; as you've written it, you end up with a blank field (which creates extra whitespace in the printout).